# Scope of $(this) in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm confused when trying to work out the scope of `$(this)` in a jQuery plugin. Take the following simple plugin:

```
;(function($){

    $.fn.somePlugin = function(options) {  

        // Defaults
        var defaults = {  

            foo: 'bar'

        };

        // Options
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);


        // Return each object
        return this.each(function() {

            // Cache $(this)
            var $this = $(this);


            // Do whatever the plugin needs to do here


            // A test public function
            $.fn.somePublicFunction = function() {

                // $this or $(this)?

            };

            // A test private function
            function privateFunction() {

                // $this or $(this)?

            }

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

From what I can gather in a ***private function*** `$this` would use the last index in the array of elements matched so would cause problems. `$(this)` is undefined. So if you wanted to reference a specific matched element you would need to pass it to the private function after using some other means to matched the specific element(s) you wish to work with. Or you can do `this.each` and loop through all matched elements if you need to.

In the ***public function***, $this is not within scope so you would have to loop through all matched elements with $(this) or this.

Is this correct? Why in `$.fn.somePublicFunction` isn't `$(this)` available? In general do public functions always apply to all matched elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` and `$(this)` are the same, and there's no difference in scope.

`$(this)` is `this`, but only converted to a jQuery object. This way, `$(this)` will be visible anywhere, where `this` is.

*`this` can be a **DOM element***

jQuery sets the scope of the callback function to the element which is the subject of the callback. For example, when you iterating a collection, setting listener or handling an event.

```
$('#id').on('click', function() {
    // this == $('#id')
}
```

*`this` can be an **Object***

For example, when you are iterating a collection of any objects.

```
var my_arr = [1, 2, 3];
$.each(arr, function(i, obj) {
    // 'this' is an object of current iteration
}
```

*`this` can be a **jQuery object***

When you're extending jQuery using `fn` extension, `this` inside a method is a jQuery object (== $):

```
$.fn.myPlug = function() {
    // this is here a jQuery object, on which the method is called
});
```

*this can also be an **AJAX settings Object** inside an AJAX query*

When you use `var $this = $(this);`, you just saving current `this` as a jQuery object to a variable with name `$this`, and if `this` is different in current context, it would not be equal to previously declared `$this`.

Comment: Thanks. Is var $this = $(this); not good practice? Also, what is can you explain the variable scope of $.fn.somePublicFunction?

Comment: $this = $(this) is used to save current `this` as jQuery object to use it in future, where current `this` will be inaccessible, modified or something else. You just save it to `$this` and you can use it anywhere, where it's visible, even if `this` changes - `$this` won't :)

Comment: And in $.fn.somePublicFunction `this` will be equal to a jQuery object, on which this method is called. For example, if you call `$('#my_div').somePublicFunction`, `this` inside the function will be equal to `$('#my_div')`.